# Can i use TTL (Time To Live) on MongoDB with collection.update?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema, ttl

I want to  expire data in  database ( its ok with expireAfterSeconds), but i want to use with collection.update>> data are always send data to database in real-time so TTL  must be working on update data.. can i do that??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Restating, I believe the intent of your question is the following:

> Do [TTL indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/) remove documents based on the current value of the specified field even if it has been updated from what it was when the document was initially written?

If I've understood your question correctly, then the answer is: Yes!

TTL deletions in MongoDB are handled by [a background operation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/#delete-operations) that runs approximately every 60 seconds. Each time it runs it will *read the index* to find any documents which have reached expiry. Expiry is determined by the combination of the `expireAfterSeconds` configuration in the index along with the value of the indexed field for each document. By definition, the value of that field is kept up to date in the index. Therefore TTL deletions can only be done on the most recent value for the field which will take into account any and all updates that have occurred prior to each run of the deletion thread. It is common to use TTL indexes to do things like session management in which this property of using the updated values for the documents is critical.

Comment: want to delete record automatically after some day
i have use index also for it